# Alternatives to C "inline" keyword

Tags: c, compiler-construction, inline, compiler-optimization, inline-code

From my course instructor, he has repeatedly emphasized and asked us not to use the "inline" keyword for functions. He says it is not "portable" across compilers and is not "standard". Considering this, are there any "standard" alternatives that allow for "inline expansion"?

Comment: Although, is there really even a need *to* use `inline`? If I was an instructor, that's what I'd warn about -- "optimization".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your course instructor is wrong. It *is* standard. It's actually *in* the current standard, right there in section `6.7.4 Function specifiers` (C99). The fact that it's a suggestion to the compiler that may be totally ignored does not make it any less standard.

I don't think it was in C89/90 which may be what some embedded compilers use but I would give *serious* consideration to upgrading in that case.

However, even where `inline` is available, I generally leave those decisions up to the compiler itself since most modern ones are more than capable of figuring out how best to optimise code (and usually far better than I). The `inline` keyword, like `register` and `auto`, is not something I normally worry about at all.

You can use macros instead since that's relatively simple text substitution that generally happens before the compile phase but you should be aware of the limitations and foibles.

Or you can manually inline code (ie, duplicate it) although I wouldn't suggest this as an option since it may quickly become a maintenance nightmare.

Myself, I would write the code using normal functions without *any* of those tricks and then introduce them where necessary (and *only* if you can demonstrate that they're needed, such as a specific performance issue).

You should always assume that the coder who has to maintain your code is a psychopathic killer who knows where you live :-)

Comment: +1 The important thing to keep in mind here is that, even though the `inline` keyword is standard, compilers have gotten to a point now where they are smarter than most of us most of the time. What your professor is *probably* getting at is that you shouldn't be trying to make these decisions yourself at all, but rather leaving it up to the compiler to decide when it is most appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, some of the code I've seen gcc emit at its "insane" optimisation level has taken me a while to understand.

Comment: Where can we find a good link that explains all those issues ? Im Another Student

Comment: Please don't take the `inline` keyword just for its wording. It is not only a hint to the compiler, but changes the visibility of function symbols. It is an important feature if you design large libraries with a lot of inline functions.

Comment: @Jens, that it does but I see that more as a side effect. Assuming that all declarations are marked `inline` and none are marked `extern`, the compiler can "hide" the function within the current translation unit. But for inline functions with external linkage, I think it's up to the implementation whether the inline or an external function is called. This particular behaviour is one of those "dark corners" of C (for me anyway since I rarely use inline, others may know better).

Comment: @paxdiablo: I wouldn't say it is a dark corner, not shining clear either. Sure it is up to the implementation to chose whether or not an external function is called, and in that it is only a hint (luckily). But the standard specifies (here comes a bit of a shadow) when and how such an external symbol is instantiated. So with a standard conforming compiler you have control over that and you avoid these crazy one-static-copy-per-unit garbage that `static` only header functions may generate.

Comment: @pax: I've actually run into problems in the past with over-inlining of functions, where the size of the resulting code was too large to fit into the processor's L1 cache. Deoptimizing by forcing things to *not* inline (a black art!) made for quite a nice improvement to code that was already fairly thoroughly tuned…

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the Visual Studio C compiler is not C99 compliant and does not support the inline keyword.  It does support an "__inline" keyword, or you can compile using their C++ compiler.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, `inline` was integrated to the C standard 11 years ago.

Other than was indicated, `inline` makes a difference since it changes the visibility properties of the function. In particular for large libraries with a lot of functions declared only `static` you might have one version of any these function in *all* object files (e.g when you compile with debugging switched on).

Please have a look into that post: [Myth and reality about inline in C99](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/myth-and-reality-about-inline-in-c99/)

Answer (score 0):

As evil as they may be, macros are still king (although specific compilers may support extra capabilities).

Answer (score 0):

Here, now it's "portable across compilers":

```
#if (__STDC_VERSION__ < 199901L)
#define inline
#endif
static inline int foobar(int x) /* ... */
```

By the way, as others have said, the `inline` keyword is just a hint and rather useless, but the important keyword is `static`. Unless your function is declared `static`, it will have external linkage, and the compiler is unlikely to consider it a candidate for inlining when it makes its own decisions about which functions to inline.

<strike>Also note that unlike in C++, the C language does not allow `inline` without `static`.</strike>

Comment: @R.: no `inline` without `static`? How do you come to that conclusion? It is difficult to use `inline` without `static` with non conforming compilers such as gcc pre-4.3, that is. But for conforming compilers using it with `inline` in the header and have one additional *declaration* without `inline` to instatiate the function in just one compilation unit should do the trick.

Comment: @Jens: That behavior is not specified by the C language. It's a compiler bastardization from C++.

Comment: @R.: yes it is explicitly specified when a definition is an *inline definition* or not. Please, read the standard.

Comment: @R.: I just have my view of that written up. You find the link in my post, if you like.

Comment: for C89 and C90 `__STDC_VERSION__` is not defined. In the case you are compiling with that standards you would we using an undeclared identifier.

Comment: @Giuppox: That's fine. In preprocessor conditionals, undefined expands to `0`.